# static int value not changing upon adding

Tags: java, junit, errorcollector

I am facing a weird issue. I have an ErrorCollector which is based on an ArrayList. I want to throw at the end of all the tests the cumulative errors that have been collected by error collector.

For that, I have written something like :

```
private static int noOfErrors;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();

    collector = new MyErrorCollector();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {

    noOfErrors = noOfErrors + collector.getErrorCount();

    for (Throwable error : collector.getErrors()) {
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }
    collector = null;
}

@AfterClass
public static void finalTearDown(){
    assertEquals(noOfErrors, 0);
}
```

But even though in my `@After` method, the collected errors in non zero, `assertEquals` method in `@AfterClass` method is not failing. Upon debugging, it is showing non zero `noOfErrors` in `tearDown` methodand vice versa for `finalTearDown`.

Comment: Why are you replicating functionality that is already in junit?

Comment: I wanted more control over the array list of throwables which i was not having with the verify() method that the Junit was providing.

Comment: Plus I added few functionality to the error collector for my convenience like finding bug within a range of asserts etc.

Comment: Asserts in After and AfterClass methods are discouraged. Their sole purpose is to perform some tidyup after each test or all the tests.

Comment: What version of junit are you using?

Comment: @JamesB Fine... but still does not implies we cannot? My question is why it isn't working ...:(

Comment: 4.8.2 is the version I am using

Comment: I sincerely don't understand the downvote but its fine to me I can trade knowledge for reputation here.

Comment: @Sourabh I agree, the downvote is harsh...upvote!